# how to get an icon to appear next to the clock?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

i built a small app in vb.net and i would like my icon to appear next to the computer clock in the taskbar. how can i do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should add a [`NotifyIcon`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.notifyicon.aspx) component to your form. Assign an icon to its `Icon` property, and set its `Visible` property to `true`, and it should appear next to the clock. You can use the various mouse events of the component to let the user interact with it, or you can assign a context menu to it.